# Creating a NService Bus Ticket using SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, nservicebus

Is there a way to create a NService Bus ticket within SSIS package.

I am new at using SSIS packages (MSSQL 2012) and was thinking of serializing an NServiceBus ticket using a SCRIPT TASK and sending it to a MSMQ queue using a Messaging Task.

Am I thinking in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have done this internally, you just have to make sure you get the serialization right.  You also have to be aware of what gets sent in the message label.  Here is what is working on v2.5 which may have to be modified for 3.x:

```
        String label = String.Format("<CorrId></CorrId><WinIdName>{0}\\Administrator</WinIdName>", Environment.MachineName);

        Message message = new Message();

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IMyMessage));

        serializer.Serialize(message.BodyStream, command);

        message.Label = label;

        MessageQueue q = new MessageQueue(queueName);

        if (q != null )
        {
            q.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
        }
```